# Rails 3: Having trouble with nested forms and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

Here's my model set up.

**Band Model**

```
has_many :bands_genres
has_many :genres, :through => :bands_genres
```

**Genre Model**

```
has_many :bands_genres
has_many :bands, :through => :bands_genres
```

**BandsGenre Model**

```
belongs_to :band
belongs_to :genre
```

I have a form where you can add a new band and then select a genre from a dropdown field that pulls from the pre-set genres in the `genre` model.

So what I ultimately need to do is set up a form so that when a band adds their band and select a genre, it creates the correct join in the `bands_genre` model.

Not sure where to start with setting up the form, controllers and models for this.

I'm running Rails 3.0.3

Comment: Do you have a song/track model as well?

Comment: No...what does that have to do with this?

Comment: BandGenres doesn't seem to warrant a model. You could do with a habtm. If you had a song model , the band model could have had many genres through" the song model. Pardon me for my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

**Band Model**

```
has_many :genres, :as => :band_genres
```

**Genre Model**

```
has_many :bands, :as => :band_genres
```

Your genre table has a `band_id`, and your band table has a `genre_id`.

**bands_controller**

```
def new
   @genres = Genre.all
   @post = Post.new
end
```

**posts/new.html.haml**
(This part I'm a little unsure of, but it roughly goes like this)

```
- form_for @post do |f|
   = f.select :genre_id, @genres, {}
   = f.submit
```

Comment: Actually, bands could have multiple genres.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few text/video casts covering this, since its a popular use case. I would encourage you to look at:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1 or its equivalent asciicast (which is a text based cast of the video).

Further I would recommend you use formtastic. Associations are managed automatically so it makes form building trivial and keeps your code tidy. And yes there are casts for that too.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1